# In spark, what is the best way to build an RDD of objects by combining other objects?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Ex. I have an RDD of (RoomId(key),RoomData object(value)) and an RDD of (RoomId(key), StudentData object(value)).

I want to end up with an RDD of RoomId(key) to a object(value) that contains both room and students in that room data.

In mapreduce I would:

- pull all the data for rooms and students
- Use a combination key of the RoomId the object belonged to and "a" or
  "b" (RoomId + a) forRoomData objects and (RoomId + b) StudentData
  objects In the reducer
- I could count on the order and take the first object as a RoomData
  object for that RoomId and add the rest of the values, as
  students,    to that RoomData object using the RoomData.addStudent() 
  method
- then output the final RoomData object.

BUT in spark:

I thought of possibly joining or appending the two RDDs together and then aggregating by key over that new RDD could work, if I created some uber Room domain object that would be created in the aggregate method and hold a summation of the RoomData and StudentData for a given RoomId, but I think there is a better way out there.

I could add an addStudent method to the RoomData object that would take a StudentData object and add that data to the RoomData object, in fact that is what I would like to do. But how should/would I combine these to RDD's in a spark fashion?

Example data

Room 1
roomID - 100
subject - French
teacher - Ms. SchoolLady
time - 12:00pm

Room 2
roomID - 101
subject - Spanish
teacher - Ms. LadyAtSchool
time - 1:00am

Student 1
roomID - 101
name - Bob Smith

Student 2
roomID - 100
name - Ryan Strong

Student 3
roomID - 100
name - Jane Smith

Rooms in roomRDD students in studentRDD, can not change the originating RDDs.

Want the result to be some RDD that contains:

Room 1
roomID - 100
subject - French
teacher - Ms. SchoolLady
time - 12:00pm
students - Ryan Strong, Jane Smith

Room 2
roomID - 101
subject - Spanish
teacher - Ms. LadyAtSchool
time - 1:00am
students - Bob Smith

Comment: please share example data and expected output

Comment: @mtoto there you go!

Comment: can you rewrite that using `sc.parallelize()` ?